# Conditional Response Check Making Karate Test Stuck

Tags: karate

We had a strange issue where karate test suddenly stuck forever. We did debugging on all of our tests and found that we do conditional response check that makes test execution stuck.

```
    * def query = karate.call('classpath:mutation/Publisher/CreatePublisher.js')
    * def variables = {publisher:{name:'#(name)', description:"Automatically generated by automation test", website:"kumparan.com", isVerified:false, isActive:false, coverMediaID:"", avatarMediaID:"", ownerIDs: ["1559121234244046737"], metaTitle: "Meta title Karate test", metaDescription: "Meta description Karate test", metaKeywords: "", slug: '#(randomSlug)'}}
    * request { query: '#(query)', variables: '#(variables)' }
    * method POST
    * print response.data
    * if (response.data.CreatePublisher == null) karate.abort()
```

The part `* if (response.data.CreatePublisher == null) karate.abort()` for sure make our test stuck. However the value of the `response.data.CreatePublisher` is indeed null (attached is the screenshot)

[image: Conditional]

It makes us wonder, whether we did the conditional check wrong or it might be a bug on karate's side? (Of which we will help making the report if it is the case)

Comment: sorry I can't read and make sense of this - so yes follow the process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0):

Are you on the latest 0.9.5.RC4 ? Or you may need to use `* eval if`